# Pandas: check if date from one dataframe is between two dates from another dataframe and sobstitute values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

df1

```
   date               event    group    failure
2018-04-19 02:07:00     1       E1         0
2018-04-19 02:07:00     2       E2         1
```

df2:

```
        start_time                   end_time           group      failure
2018-04-01 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-01 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-27 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-27 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-27 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-27 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-26 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-26 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-26 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-26 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-25 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-25 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-25 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-25 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-24 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-24 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-24 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-24 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-23 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-23 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-23 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-23 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-16 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-22 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-28 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-29 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-07 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-08 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-06 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-06 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-06 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-06 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-09 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-15 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-05 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-05 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-04 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-04 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-03 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-03 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-02 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-02 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-04 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-04 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-05 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-05 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-03 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-03 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-27 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-27 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-02 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-02 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-26 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-26 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-25 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-25 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-03 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-03 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-26 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-26 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-27 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-27 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-01 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-01 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-25 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-25 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-03 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-03 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-24 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-24 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-04 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-04 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-24 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-24 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-23 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-23 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-04 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-04 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-23 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-23 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-16 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-22 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-05 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-05 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-09 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-15 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-07 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-08 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-05 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-05 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-06 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-06 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-06 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-06 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-28 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-29 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
```

I have to check if:

- df1(date) is between df2(start_time) and df2(end_time)
- df1(group)=df2(group)

then replace df2(failure) with df1(failure).
The desired outcome looks like:

```
        start_time                   end_time           group      failure
2018-04-01 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-01 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-27 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-27 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-27 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-27 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-26 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-26 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-26 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-26 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-25 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-25 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-25 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-25 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-24 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-24 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-24 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-24 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-23 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-23 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-23 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-23 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-16 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-22 23:59:59+01:00     E1         0
2018-04-28 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-29 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-07 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-08 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-06 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-06 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-06 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-06 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-09 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-15 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-05 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-05 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-04 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-04 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-03 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-03 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-02 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-02 23:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-04 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-04 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-05 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-05 12:59:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-03 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-03 21:29:59+01:00     E1         1
2018-04-27 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-27 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-02 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-02 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-26 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-26 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-25 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-25 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-03 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-03 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-26 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-26 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-27 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-27 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-01 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-01 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-25 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-25 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-03 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-03 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-24 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-24 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-04 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-04 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-24 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-24 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-23 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-23 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-04 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-04 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-23 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-23 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-16 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-22 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-05 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-05 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-09 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-15 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-07 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-08 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-05 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-05 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-06 19:00:00+01:00   2018-04-06 21:29:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-06 06:00:00+01:00   2018-04-06 12:59:59+01:00     E2         1
2018-04-28 00:00:00+01:00   2018-04-29 23:59:59+01:00     E2         1
```

I have tried with if functions, but I get the error: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects. Any suggestion? Thank you in advance!

Comment: try:

`df1[~df1.date.isin(df2.start_time.values)]`   at  least this give you the idea if it matches the records you are looking in..

Comment: I don't get any error, but it doesn't change the value!

Comment: are both of your columns datetime objects? the error you receive might indicate that one of them is a string and the other one is a datetime

Comment: Yeah, it not change value just checking  if the values from `date` columns are matching anywhere in the df2 `start_time` columns. replace logic still to implement..

Comment: @DanielR. he is not getting any error :-)

Comment: They are both datetime64

Comment: I suggest you build an intervalindex, maybe it helps https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#intervalindex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could compare the dates after doing the following:-

```
e1['date'] = e1['date'].apply( lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).tz_localize('US/Eastern'))
e2['start_time'] = e2['start_time'].apply( lambda x: 
pd.to_datetime(x).tz_localize('US/Eastern'))
e2['end_time'] = e2['end_time'].apply( lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).tz_localize('US/Eastern'))
```

I merged both tables  and then checked if date is between start time and end time to replace failure variable.

failure_x is of E2 while failure_y is of E1 dataframes:-

```
df = e2.merge(e1,on='group',how='left')
df['failure_x'] = np.where((df['start_time'] <= df['date']) & (df['date'] <=  df['end_time']), df['failure_y'], df['failure_x'])
```

Comment: haven't you mistaken a bit with all those "df"?
I mean, which should be df, df1 or df2